# C# RichTextBox Format not shown if text loaded

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I've got a RichTextBox in which I can format the text..

I can save the text as .txt and also **load**,

but when **loaded**, the *formatting* of the text is "away"..

So what can I do, that the format **stay**?

Hope someone can help me..

Comment: what do you mean the format of text is AWAY?

Comment: for example I make the text BOLD, after loading the textfile it is back to Regular/Normal Style..

Comment: Use RTF file formats and not TXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the RTF format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e(v=vs.80).aspx

TXT only saves the text but no formatting.